# AWS API Gateway Calls not working for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, retrofit2, http-status-code-403, aws-api-gateway

I have a custom API set up on AWS for passing a message to the server. The server then responds to that message in a simple fashion. The API calls work from the browser and Postman, but do not work via the mobile client. I've removed authorization on the API, deployed it, and triple checked my api calls, but I continue to receive the 403 "Forbidden" error. I'm calling the API using Retrofit. Here is my client code:

API Calls:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface MyAPI {
    @Headers({
            "content-type: application/json",
            "Accept: application/json"
    })
    @POST("/chat/new")
    Call<ChatMessageBody> postMessage(@Body ChatMessageBody message);
}
```

ChatMessageBody class:

```
public class ChatMessageBody {

    private String messageBody;

    public ChatMessageBody(String body){
        this.messageBody = body;
    }

    public String body() {
        return messageBody;
    }
}
```

Theoretically, the Request Body of my call as a result of the set up should be something like this:

```
{
     "messageBody" : "This is my message"
}
```

Am I missing a vital aspect of calling the API from a mobile setting? It doesn't make sense to me that I'd be able to call the API endpoint from my browser and through Postman and have it work, yet I can't seem to do so via Android.

EDIT:
Response Body from a successful call (via postman or API Gateway test)

```
{\"messageBody\": \"You said \\\"test\\\"\"}
```

Response Body from the 403 error

```
{"message":"Forbidden"}
```

Postman generates code based on your desired client and your calls. Here is the code generated for this call by Postman (with respect to OkHTTP. I'm not using this code, but it could provide insight into why Postman works and my client doesn't):

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\n\t\"messageBody\" : \"test\"\n}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://qj2wkyi91c.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prototype_mvp/chat/new")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
  .addHeader("postman-token", "dccf1f20-f20e-fd53-dd24-a9f4ae7b5c69")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Here is a stack trace of my requests/responses in the Android Environment:

```
03-27 12:32:27.835 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: --> POST [MY_API_ENDPOINT] http/1.1
03-27 12:32:27.835 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
03-27 12:32:27.835 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 36
03-27 12:32:27.835 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: Accept: application/json
03-27 12:32:27.836 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: {"messageBody":"This is my message"}
03-27 12:32:27.836 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: --> END POST (36-byte body)
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: <-- 403  [MY_API_ENDPOINT] (239ms)
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: content-type: application/json
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: content-length: 24
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: date: Mon, 27 Mar 2017 16:32:28 GMT
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: x-amzn-requestid: [REQUEST_ID]
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: x-cache: Error from cloudfront
03-27 12:32:28.076 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: via: 1.1 [CLOUDFRONT_URL] (CloudFront)
03-27 12:32:28.077 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: x-amz-cf-id: [CF_ID]
03-27 12:32:28.077 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: {"message":"Forbidden"}
03-27 12:32:28.077 29985-31080/com.dev.example.debug D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (24-byte body)
03-27 12:32:28.079 29985-29985/com.dev.example.debug E/MyAPI: Your request did not receive a successful response.
03-27 12:32:28.079 29985-29985/com.dev.example.debug E/MyAPI: Response Error Code: 403
03-27 12:32:28.079 29985-29985/com.dev.example.debug E/MyAPI: Response Body: {"message":"Forbidden"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue by abandoning Retrofit and designing an OKHttp client which interfaces with AWS. My requests are now being properly signed for AWS, and I'm no longer receiving 403 errors.

Comment: Hy John, I am stuck with the same issue that you mentioned in your question. And I am not able to resolve the issue. It would be really thankful if you could please help me on this issue.

Comment: Can you describe the structure of your API Gateway? For example what kind of requests are you sending, are you using CORS, etc.

Comment: Hy @John Riley, You can refer to the link on which my colleague posted the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45895647/2648780 Posted one is the way how we are implementing in our app.

Comment: @vishalsharma I did not use Retrofit to reach my solution. I'd recommend learning OkHttp and implementing your client using that instead.

Comment: it would be really nice if you could share some link or code on how to implement as I had thought it would be easy to implement aws api using retrofit as the normal api but it didn't and I have to release the build by end of this weekend and have no clue over it. Sorry for being too demanding.

Comment: The code I used for my project isn't public, so unfortunately I can't really share any example code straight away.

Here's a tutorial for OkHttp on Vogella: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-OkHttp/article.html

You should also look into how to use the 'AWS4Signer' class in parallel with this in order to sign your requests appropriately.

Comment: no problem...btw thanks for the quick reply. will try to use above link.

Comment: Is there necessary to use AWS4Signer as iOS platform can easily access all the APIs without having these things?

Comment: @vishalsharma For Android I found it necessary to use the AWS4Signer on my requests, as my API requires credential checks. Perhaps an open API might not require this. It's been a while since I've worked on this, so I don't recall.

Answer (score 2):

There is no authorization in that request, therefore the response given back is forbidden accessing that route.

Also the content type can affect that, postman conveniently deals with this behind the scenes, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I turned authorization off for the method in question, and my api doesn't require a key, so what would be the steps I need to take to configure authorization for my mobile client? All of the resources I've checked stated that unless you set authorization or an API key, you should be able to call it freely.

Comment: post the full response body of the api call?

Comment: I just edited my original post to contain response bodies from both successful and failed API calls.

Answer (score 0):

403 (Permission Denied) can also occur if you send a request to the wrong path.

I'm not familiar with retrofit, but see you only have `/chat/new` listed in your annotation. How do you configure the root path in retrofit?

Are you sure you are including the full path including stage?

Comment: The root path is added at runtime with a Builder class. I've checked and I'm using the correct end point. The stack trace in my post shows [MY_API_ENDPOINT], where that url is the API Endpoint including the stage and resource.

Answer (score 0):

Created an [AWS Gateway OkHttp Interceptor](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor) for those who prefer Retrofit over the AWS sdk. It still uses `AWS4Signer` from `aws-android-sdk-apigateway-core` tho, so you have to keep this dependency in your project.